# How are diffeomorphisms related to tangent spaces? Why does $F$ invertible $\implies$ $dFp$ invertible?

Tags: differential-geometry

How are diffeomorphisms related to tangent spaces?

If $F: M \rightarrow N$ is diffeomorphism, then what does this say about $dFp : T_pM \rightarrow T_{F(p)}N$?

What I intuitively think is that if $F$ is diffeomorphic, i.e. differentiable, then this could "transfer" properties that are retained in derivatives to $dFp$.

However, I'm unsure as to what these properties are and why?

Particularly, why does e.g. $F$ invertible $\implies$ $dFp$ invertible?

Comment: If $F: M \rightarrow N$ is diffeomorphism then $dFp : T_pM \rightarrow T_{F(p)}N$ is an isomorphism between vector spaces.

Comment: @mfl Yes this is what I'm trying to prove actually. But I don't understand why does $F$ invertible $\implies$ $dFp$ invertible?

Comment: You should be able to find this fact in any book on smooth manifolds. It is just chain rule: $d(G\circ F)_p=dG_{F(p)}\circ dF_p$. This makes the derivative a covariant functor, and covariant functor in general sends isomorphisms to isomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find this fact in any book on smooth manifolds. It is just chain rule: $d(G\circ F)_p=dG_{F(p)}\circ dF_p$. Combining with that $d(id_M)_p=id_{T_pM}$ for the identity map $id_M$ on $M$, this makes the derivative $F\mapsto dF_p$ a covariant functor, and covariant functor in general sends isomorphisms to isomorphisms, by the following observation:

If $G$ is the inverse of $F$, then $id=d(G\circ F)=dG\circ dF$, while $id=d(F\circ G)=dF\circ dG$, i.e. $dF$ and $dG$ are inverse functions of each other.

Comment: I have not had the concept of covariant functions. But perhaps one can also rely on that "a linear function is an isomorphism iff it's invertible"? Since the derivative is a linear operator.

Comment: @mavavilj Covariant functor, not function. And yes, by definition, a linear map ($dF_p$ in our case) is an isomorphism if there exists a linear map as its inverse.